# T-SQL COALESCE does not return distinct values

Tags: sql, pivot, coalesce

This query returns duplicate values for Zip - which I don't think it should.
For example: @pivotColumns returns the following list even when the sub-query for zip has a "distinct Zip".
I am assuming the QUOTENAME might not be working well for the purposes of a returning a list of unique values? I want the ZipCode's with no duplicates

```
DECLARE   @PivotColumns AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT   @PivotColumns = COALESCE (@PivotColumns + ',','') + QUOTENAME([Zip])
FROM [dbo].[PivotStoreZip]
Where Zip in (
               Select distinct Zip 
               From PivotStoreZip 
               Where ZIP in ('39401','39402', '39406','39465','39475')
             )

print (@PivotColumns)
```

the `print (@PivotColumns)` returns the list below and, for example, `[39401]` repeats:

```
[39401],[39406],[39465],[39475],[39401],[39402],[39406],[39465],[39475]
```

Comment: `coalesce` want return distinct values & i suspect variable `@PivotColumns` already has the similar  values.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `distinct` in a subquery to remove duplicate `Zip` instead of `where` condition

```
SELECT   @PivotColumns = COALESCE (@PivotColumns + ',','') + QUOTENAME([Zip])
FROM (
    Select distinct Zip 
    From PivotStoreZip 
    Where ZIP in ('39401','39402', '39406','39465','39475')
) t1
```

Answer (score 0):

The `distinct` in the `in` is of no use.  `in` doesn't generate duplicates and this has no effect on the outer query.

I think you want to do:

```
select  @PivotColumns = COALESCE (@PivotColumns + ',','') + QUOTENAME([Zip])
from (select distinct Zip 
      from PivotStoreZip 
      where ZIP in ('39401', '39402', '39406', '39465', '39475')
     ) z;
```

I should note that this works in practice.  I'm not 100% sure that Microsoft guarantees that this code works in general.

Answer (score 0):

The distinct in the subquery is not enough, as if you have duplicates in `[dbo].[PivotStoreZip]` they will pop up from your main query, so just add a distinct there too:

```
DECLARE   @PivotColumns AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT   @PivotColumns = distinct COALESCE (@PivotColumns + ',','') + QUOTENAME([Zip])
FROM [dbo].[PivotStoreZip]
Where Zip in (
               Select distinct Zip 
               From PivotStoreZip 
               Where ZIP in ('39401','39402', '39406','39465','39475')
             )
```

print (@PivotColumns)